# No se encuentra el punto de entrada C++

Tags: clase, c++11

estoy empezando a programar en C++ , ya he realizado algunos pequeños prgramas y compilarlos correctamente , pero cuando empece las clases en C++ al compilarlo y ejecutar el programa me sale este error.

[image: Error!]

Este es mi codigo .  Main.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Persona.h"  
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
    Persona persona1("Luis Gomez");
    Persona persona2("Pepe el toro");

    persona1.setEdad(15);
    persona1.setTel("5515662962");
    persona1.setPeso(65);

    persona2.setEdad(19);
    persona2.setTel("5564484568");
    persona2.setPeso(58);

    cout << "\n Datos de : " << persona1.getNombre() << "\n"
         << " Edad : " << persona1.getEdad() << "\n"
         << " Telefono : " << persona1.getTel() << "\n"
         << " Peso : "<<  persona1.getPeso() << "\n" 
         << endl;

    cout << "\n Datos de : " << persona2.getNombre() << "\n"
        << " Edad : " << persona2.getEdad() << "\n"
        << " Telefono : "<< persona2.getTel() << "\n"
        << " Peso : "<< persona2.getPeso() << "\n" << endl;

 return 0;
}
```

Codigo clase Persona .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Persona {
    private :
        int edad;
        string nomb;
        int peso;
        string tel;

    public :
    // constructor
    explicit Persona(string nombre){
      setNombre(nombre);
    }

    // Setters

    void setNombre(string nombre){
        nomb = nombre;
    }

    void setEdad(int eda){
        edad = eda;
    }

    void setTel(string telefono){
        tel = telefono;
    }

    void setPeso(int pes){
        peso = pes;
    }
    // Getters

    int getEdad(){
        return edad;
    }
    string getNombre(){
        return nomb;
    }

    int getPeso(){
        return peso;
    }

    string getTel(){
        return tel;
    }
};
```

Espero sus respuestas , espero puedan ayudarme , gracias.

Comment: Haz intentado recopilar Te paso unos links espero te puedan ayudar
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841721/why-cant-a-procedure-entry-point-could-not-be-located-in-dll-when-i-definitel https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841721/why-cant-a-procedure-entry-point-could-not-be-located-in-dll-when-i-definitel

Comment: si borras la palabra reservada explicit?

Comment: Me sale el mismo error.

Comment: No me funcionó. Alguna otra sugerencia ?

Comment: tu ide no sabe que clase compilar mira https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/f9t8842e.aspx

Comment: He estado intentándolo , pero sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: Dev que tal si lo instalas de nuevo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es un problema de instalación/entorno.

## Símbolos

Cada vez que tu compilas un código, una vez compilado el `.cpp`, dicha unidad de compilación es transformada a un **código objeto** (fichero con extensión `.o`). Tu `prueba.o` es pasado al enlazador, quien finalmente genera un ejecutable (`prueba.exe`). `prueba.o` finalmente es eliminado, ya que es un objeto intermedio. El enlazador es en realidad otro programa diferente, llamado `ld`, que es utilizado internamente por `gcc` para que no seas tú quién realice los dos pasos manualmente.

Desde el punto de vista del enlazador, cada nombre de variable global, variable estática o nombre de función (sea función externa o una función miembro), de cada **código objeto**, es llamada `símbolo`.

¿Qué símbolos tiene tu ejecutable? Pues todas las funciones de la clase `persona`, `main`, todos los símbolos que haya en el fichero `<string>`, y todos los símbolos que haya en el fichero `<iostream>`, ya que son todos los ficheros que incluyes en tu programa.

Bueno pues resulta, que hay un símbolo de la clase `std::string` (un `std::string` es en realidad un `typedef` de `std::basic_string<char>`), que por algún motivo no está definido en el ejecutable, aunque al mismo tiempo, es llamado desde el propio ejecutable.

Al intentar llamar a dicho símbolo (dicho método), éste no aparece en el ejecutable, de ahí que te diga que no lo encuentra. Así que algo mal está pasando en el proceso de compilación/enlazado, que los símbolos no se están "administrando" bien.

## Name Mangling

¿Por qué no viene, en la descripción del error, escrito el nombre del símbolo problemático *en cristiano*? Porque, debido a que C++ tiene sobrecarga de funciones y operadores, además de espacios de nombres, y por tanto, puede haber funciones y operaciones que se llaman igual, los compiladores realizan una cosa que se llama `name mangling`.

Fundamentalmente, es darle a cada función/sobrecarga un nombre único, ya que el enlazador "solo entiende de C", donde cada nombre es único (por decirlo de alguna manera, por eso lo de las comillas). Los nombres están pensandos para evitar conflictos, y además cada compilador y en cada plataforma realiza un *name mangling* diferente (de hay la gran polución de cosas sin sentido, normalmente carácteres que indican el tipo, y números que indican la cantidad de parámetros o la longitud de cada nombre). Saber el método problemático en particular es imposible, a no ser que dispongas del **name demangler** de tu plataforma.

Es probable que al compilar, el compilador le haya dado un nombre a una función u operador en el punto de llamada (es decir, cuando la utilizas), que no coincide con el nombre generado para la función de la librería.

Mi hipótesis a lo mejor es que no has hecho una instalación desde cero, y a lo mejor has instalado las librerías desde fuentes diferentes al compilador, o has instalado diferentes versiones no satisfactoriamente, o cuando instalaste el compilador ya estaban ciertas librerías instaladas por otros motivos, o has hecho una actualización que no se ha completado bien, etc. O puede que haya incluso versiones precompiladas de dichas librerías con los nombres ya generados: puede que exista una versión ya compilada de `<string>`, con nombres generados diferentes a los que el compilador genera en el punto de llamada en tu código; al existir una versión ya compilada, el compilador utiliza éstos y se salta el procesamiento de la línea `#include <string>`, resultando al final que el trato de nombres dado a esa versión precompilada, es diferente al trato de nombres dado a tu fichero.

En cualquier caso, o bien hay conflictos con los nombres, o bien, sencillamente, no se compila bien y la función miembro ni siquiera existe o ha desaparecido.

## Conclusión

Tu código es correcto, y tu línea de compilación es correcta (lo he compilado por mi cuenta y ejecuta correctamente), así que el problema es 100% seguro de entorno.

Así que debes reinstalarlo todo, o mejor aún, trabajar en una máquina virtual limpia e instalar y desarrollar allí. Cosas de Windows. Pasarte a Linux para desarrollar también es una opción :).

Comment: Muchas gracias compañero , la solución fue pasarme a linux , volví a instalar todo de nuevo y me volvía a salir el error a si que mejor instale una distribución de linux y empezar a desarrollar desde ahí y funciono bien. De nuevo muchas gracias